# realm multiple classes error opening istance

Tags: android, realm, realm-js

I have a .realm file with 5 classes and I want to open that .realm file and read a column of one class but when I try to access the database I receive an error. It's an app for Android made in react native.This is the function I use to read data from database:

```
async retriveArticle() {
let output = null;
try {
let variable = await Realm.open(await domainDatabaseOptions());
output = variable.objects(questionari.name);console.log("output : ", 
output); return output;
} catch (error) {
ErrLog("Error on retriving articles from db", error);
}
}
```

The function domainDatabaseOptions return the schemas and path of the .realm file.
I tried with a .realm file with only one class and it works but when I add another class nothing works. I made the database using .csv files.

Comment: So what's in the error?